# HTML audio element fails to load audio stream

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have assembled a website and configured a Digital Ocean droplet to serve an audio stream using Azuracast.

At this URL http://137.184.153.182:8010/radio.mp3 lives the live audio stream. At the time of posting I am streaming static from Audio Hijack, which you can hear by visiting the URL and clicking play on the audio element. By inspecting the site I see the following HTML

`<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"> <source src="http://137.184.153.182:8010/radio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>`

On the site meant to deliver the audio stream to listeners https://feverdream.radio, I have placed an identical HTML snippet. However the play button remains grayed out and I am unable to play the audio live stream.

I do not understand what I could be doing wrong so that the same code is functional on one URL but not another.

Comment: GET https://137.184.153.182:8010/radio.mp3 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID this is i am observed from url you provided i think you need to make your audio like https

Comment: So you are using the `<video>` element to play audio? Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an insecure HTTP resource is being loaded for an HTTPs website.  Open the browser console to see the error below:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://feverdream.radio/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://137.184.153.182:8010/radio.mp3'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

The SSL/TLS certificate authority for `137.184.153.182` should be either:

1. Publicly issued - see [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)
2. Privately trusted - see [how to trust a self signed certificate](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+trust+a+self+signed+certificate) for your non-public development environment.